# Passing a value through constructor in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

> I am passing a value in my product page but it is coming as null even when the value that I am passing is not null.

```
onTap: () {
          setState(() {
             ProductListPage(uid: arguments["userId"],);
                 print(arguments["userId"]);
          });
```

> This is the code for product page

```
const ProductListPage({Key? key, this.uid}) : super(key: key);
final uid;

@override
  _ProductListPageState createState() => _ProductListPageState();
}

class _ProductListPageState extends State<ProductListPage>
void getProducts() async {
print("new id");
print(widget.uid);
}
```

Comment: in your first part of the code, have you checked what's inside "arguments["userId"]"? If you're sending a null value, that's what you're going to get over the new class.

Comment: You're constructing a `ProductListPage` but then don't do anything with the constructed object, so it gets discarded and destroyed.  Whatever `ProductListPage` you're calling `getProducts` on almost certainly is a different instance.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla yes I have checked it, the value that I am passing is not null.

Comment: could you print both stages with the logs here? Plus, your logic doesn't look correct. onTap should be using MaterialPageRoute (if is a new screen) or a Dialog (if is the case) and not updating a State for a StatefulWidget

Comment: @jamesdlin how to fix this?

Comment: I don't know what the rest of your code is, so I can't tell you how to fix it.  You presumably want to assign the constructed `ProductListPage` to a member or possibly want to mutate an existing `_ProductListPageState`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to setState outside ProductListPage (which you probably are), it won't work that way.

If whatever you are pressing is passed from ProductListPage, you would pass a setState function to that widget from ProductListPage, so you can call that function to setState in ProductListPage when that widget is pressed.

In your case, your setState is only happening in the stateful widget that is being pressed.

If your button isn't passed from ProductListPage, you'll need to use a state management solution like the [Provider Package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) or [RiverPod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod).